# Is there a word with a negative connotation for someone in the first year of secondary school?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm (making a poor attempt at) writing a novel, set from the perspective of someone in sixth form. Is there any word that I can use to describe someone who's in their first year of secondary school?  I'd prefer a UK based term, if possible.
For anyone who happens to also speak Dutch, I'm looking for the equivalent of 'bruggertje'.

Comment: What is “sixth form”? That is, how old are the kids?

Comment: @Laurel Sixth form is the last year of secondary school, so you'd be 16 or 17.

Comment: @WalrusGumboot Locale is important— in the U.S., "secondary school" means high school (ages 14–17), and there isn't any universal term of disparagement for freshmen (except, perhaps, *freshmen* itself said with a sneer), though individual schools may have their own terminology.

Comment: @choster I see, I didn't really make this clear in my question. I'm looking for a UK based term.

Comment: Frosh would be a US-based term. I'm thinking that there are terms that fit what you need, although anything that is existing on the edges of my memory is going to be from the first half of the twentieth century and probably not in current usage.

Comment: @WalrusGumboot Please [edit] this information into your original post. I would strongly recommend you review the guidance for [single word requests](/tags/single-word-requests/info), as well as the site [tour] and [help] if you are new to Stack Exchange.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110238/discussion-on-question-by-walrusgumboot-is-there-a-word-with-a-negative-connotat).